# Virtual com communications with no usb2uart bridge?

Tags: serial-port, cdc, usb-otg

I'd like to connect a beagleboard-like (custom developed) omap board to a Windows PC using a virtual-com setup. That is, i'd like the board to appear to Windows as a com device and get the COM to send data to our application on the board. The main reason for that is to use virtual-com drivers on windows, since the usb drivers we use now to directly sent data over usb between the host and the board seem not to work properly.

I have done this using the FTDI driver on the past but as far as i know it worked because the device had an FTDI chip that translated the usb protocol to serial signals (am i right ?).If there's no USB to UART bridge on the board, how could i do that ?

By the way, how USB Communication Device Classes fits here ? Should develop a CDC driver for the board ? What should I use then on Windows side ?

I'm kind of confused, so any help will be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Does your platform have a USB host on-board?

Comment: Yes, it has an USB host and an USB OTG

Comment: What OS will you be running on the OMAP board - is this Android or Linux based? I know that your question asks about a solution with no USB to UART Bridge, but you could use the bridge as a USB device as a cable that plugs in to the USB host, it doesn't necessarily need to be attached directly to your board.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your last comment. The OMAP board runs linux. Basically I want to know how can I make the device appear as a virtual-com. For example, how could I make an android device with no usb2uart but with usb otg appear as a virtual com when connected to the pc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, i answer myself :)

The solution lies in the Linux USB Gadget Subsystem.

[Gadget API](http://free-electrons.com/kerneldoc/latest/DocBook/gadget/index.html)